# Вывод данных в DataGridView из базы данных .mdf

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Возможен вывод данных в DataGridView из базы данных формата .mdf?
Т.е. возможно ли подключить файл .mdf в настройках DataGridView для этого?

Comment: То есть вы хотите файл, предназначенный для чтения сервером базы данных прочитать в приложении Winforms минуя сервер баз данных. Зачем это вам нужно?

Comment: @aepot, в sql server соединение с базой данных .mdf - активно т.е. работает. и хочу прочитать в приложении своем WindForms чтобы данные отображались в DataGridView. Такое возможно?

Comment: @aepot, зачем нужно - для чтого чтобы можно было редактировать в дальнейшем данные которые будут в DataGridView

Comment: @aepot, ответьте такое возможно?

Comment: [Add new data sources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/add-new-data-sources?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Да, просто надо понятнее вопрос формулировать. Ссылка выше.

Comment: @aepot, можно реализовать редактирование, добавление и т.д. т.е. в textbox пишется что-то потом нажимаем сохранить и данные записываются в базу данных .mdf?

Comment: Лучше начните с изучения того, какие базы данных бывают и как ими пользоваться. Ответ на ваш комментарий где-то там.

Comment: @aepot, конкретно SQL Server и .mdf пользуюсь крайне редко. поэтому интересует. возможна ли прямая запись в файл через WinForms? Дает такую возможность...

Comment: @maximum не возможна.

Comment: @maximum, а если с помощью SQL запросов в коде? а в DataGridView просто отображается. такое возможно?